# Php hash within hash issue

Tags: php

Lets say I have:

```
Data={Alex: {height: 6, weight: 160}, Rez: {height: 5.6, weight: 158}};
```

How can I access the value for Rez's weight (weight: 158), without implementing the foreach method in php?

Would it be something along the lines of `$_POST['Rez']['weight]`?

Comment: That's not a hash, that's a [json encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) string.

Comment: have you tried your suggestion? Did it work?

Comment: It is not even JSON, it is Javascript code.

Comment: @axiac  Good point, missed that part.

Comment: Assuming `$data` is valid JSON, read about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and use its second argument.

Comment: My question is "where do you HAVE that"? Is it in a javascript block, is that something you actually have in php (but formatted entirely different). I mean, the code snip you show, doesn't make any sense with only the 'php' tag on the question.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear / misinterpreting my problem. No the above code i posted did not work. "data" is passed through an ajax method and picked up via $_POST in my php script, the question was really how can I access the "weight" value within php. Also, thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have a valid JSON string (i.e. correctly quoted, etc) somewhere, there are two ways of decoding it into a native PHP data structure:

**Into nested objects:**

```
$data = json_decode($json)
$rezWeight = $data->Rez->weight;
```

**Into nested arrays:**

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$rezWeight = $data['Rez']['weight'];
```

Using either of these approaches, the `$rezWeight` variable will end up as *158*. Importantly in either case, no, you don't need to implement a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you have to decode the JSON first.. but your JSON looks a little strange.

```
$data = '{"Alex": 
             {"height": "6", "weight": "160"}, 
          "Rez": 
             {"height": "5.6", "weight": "158"}
          }';
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$height = $array['Alex']['height'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.